# Guice how to inject implementations of an interface from another module?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

In our project, we have module A which is the API module and module B the implementation module that depends on module A. In module A there is a requirement to use one of the interfaces from module A, whose implementations reside in module B. Is there a way to inject the implementations into the required point in module A? By modules I mean different projects (Gradle projects).

```
@Inject private MyInterface myInterface  // module A

public class MyInterfaceImpl1 extends MyInterface // module B depends on module A

public class MyInterfaceImpl2 extends MyInterface // module B depends on module A
```

We currently are able to do this for EJBs where we have an EJB lookup mechanism that fetches the implementation class at runtime (module A having EJB interfaces and module B the respective implementations). i do not want to make my implementation classes as EJBs and want to do the same with Guice. Is it possible? I looked at ProviderLookup class from Guice but am not sure if it is applicable. Can I also do a named injection to pick up one of the implementing classes?

Thanks,
Paddy

Comment: If your external interfaces (like `MyInterface`) are known at compile time, can you just write a `@Provides` method that reflectively loads, instantiates, and returns the correct implementation?

Comment: Is the binary in module A or module B or in some other module/project/etc.?

If it is in some other module or in module B, then you can just give the ModuleAModule and ModuleBModule instances to the injector and everything will wire up. Put a requireBinding(MyInterface.class) into ModuleAModule and use a provider or a simple binding in ModuleBModule to bind MyInterface.class to something. If the binary is in ModuleA then you obviously have to use reflection to prevent a dependency cycle. I don't know of anything in Guice that would do that for you.

Comment: Have you figured it our? I have the similar issue.